# Is it possible to get the width of the window in em units using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, font-size

I'm looking for a reliable way to get the width of the window in em units using JavaScript. I was surprised to see that jQuery will only return a result in pixel measurements.

Comment: em is relative to the size of your fonts. If your font size is 12 px, then the width of the window divided by 12 will give you the equivelant em amount. It's going to depend on what font you want this to be relative to

Answer (score 57, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
$(window).width() / parseFloat($("body").css("font-size"));
```

Comment: For those relying on font-size % and media queries change $("body").css("font-size") to $("html").css("font-size") to get a most accurate window width in ems.

Comment: The nice thing about this approach is that it becomes extremely flexible, as one can change the **$(window).width()**, to whatever the target is.

Answer (score 37):

Here's a solution that doesn't require jQuery, and doesn't require an explicit font-size declaration.

```
window.innerWidth / parseFloat(
  getComputedStyle(
    document.querySelector('body')
  )['font-size']
)
```

Comment: +1 - won't make a difference but `html` would be somewhat *more correct* than `body` for em takes the root font size and that's html's

Comment: For cross browser compatibility var width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth; and then divide width by parseFloat( as shown above).  Thank you for your posting!

Answer (score 1):

For those who need it all put together, this code works for me:

```
<p>Window size: <span id="width_px"></span> pixels or <span id="width_ems"></span> ems</p>
<script>
  window.onresize = function() {
    document.getElementById("width_px").innerHTML = window.innerWidth;
    document.getElementById("width_ems").innerHTML = window.innerWidth / parseFloat($("body").css("font-size"));
  };
</script>
```

It's put together using the answer above added to the [window-width test code](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2013/07/22/simple-responsive-images-with-css-backgrounds/) found in the linked tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to calculate it, but `em` isn't a "simple" unit like `px` because it depends on a font selection (that is, a combination of typeface family, style (bold, italic, etc), and font size). Of course font size itself can be relative (e.g. if you give a font an `em`, `ex`, or percentage size then the computed `px` height for that font is derived from the parent element's size).

To get the `em` width of a page you could do the conversion like this (warning: psuedocode):

```
// For this to work reliably, size should be in px, pt, or mm.
function getWindowWidthInEm(fontFamily, style, size) {
    var box = document.createElement("span");
    box.innerText = "M";
    box.style.fontFamily = fontFamily;
    box.style.fontSize   = size;
    box.style.fontWeight = style is bold;
    box.style.fontStyle  = style is italic;

    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    body.appendChild( box );

    var emInPx = box.getComputedStyle().width;

    body.removeChild( box );

    var windowPx = window.width;
    return windowx / emInPx;
}
```

Answer (score -21):

Simple, since we know `1em = 16px`

```
var window_width_em = 1/16 * window_width_px;
```

Comment: Assuming 1em to be 16 px is misleadingly incorrect.  Em units are relative to the cascaded font size of an element.  Adding the css `html { font-size: 10px; }` or `html { font-size: 1.5em; }` would result in 1em ***!=*** 16px.  Further out of the developers control is the fact that the "standard 16px font size" is set by the user agent, and can ***be changed by the user at a whim***.

Comment: This answer is still wrong, no matter how many of my answers you down vote :)